# R: Maximum Partial Likelihood - covariance matrix with negative values on main diagonal

Tags: r, statistics, covariance, survival-analysis

I am having a problem with the `aftreg` function of the `eha` package.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3u48w338db4piy/base_modelo_sobrevivencia2.csv?dl=0) is my database.

When I run this code:

```
base <- read.csv2([local]\\base_modelo_sobrevivencia2.csv", sep=";")
base.mod <- base[ , c(1,6,16:23, 25:72)]
base.mod <- base.mod[base.mod$TEMPO_INI_OBRA > 0, ]

for (i in 11:58) {
    base.mod[, i] <- as.factor(trimws(base.mod[, i], which="both"))
    base.mod[, i] <- factor(base.mod[, i])
} ### For cleaning the typing problem categories

attach(base.mod)

surv.inic <- Surv(TEMPO_INI_OBRA, RISCO_INI_OBRA)

    predictors <- c("RECURSO_OBRA_PAC", "MEM_DESCR_EMPREEND",      "COMPR_OPER_SIST_AGUA"   "PLANTA_SAA_LOCAL", "PECA_PB_ESCALA",  
"DOC_CONSELHO", "ART_CAPTACAO", "ART_PB_PLAN_ORC", "TITULARIDADE_TERRENO", "SUSTENT_DEVIDA", PLAN_ORC_ADM_LOCAL", "LAUDO_HIDR_PERF", "ACORDO_LEI_11445", "ETAPA_UTIL", "ANUN_CONCESS_AGUA_OPER", "METAS", "REALIDADE_LOCAL", "OBRA_EM_EXECUCAO", "TIPO", "SIT_OBRA_PAC", "COMPR_TITULARIDADE","LIC_AMB_EMPREEND")

model.ini.log <- aftreg(surv.inic ~., data=base.mod[ , predictors],
dist = "loglogistic", param = "lifeAcc")
```

Many of the *p-values* in the result return `Nan` values.

```
summary(model.ini.log)

Call:
aftreg(formula = surv.inic ~ ., data = base.mod[, predictors], 
    dist = "loglogistic", param = "lifeAcc")

Covariate          W.mean      Coef Time-Accn  se(Coef)    Wald p
RECURSO_OBRA_PAC 
             Não    0.878     0         1           (reference)
             Sim    0.122     0.539     1.715     0.395     0.173 
MEM_DESCR_EMPREEND 
             Não    0.118     0         1           (reference)
    Parcialmente    0.336    -0.273     0.761     0.127     0.031 
             Sim    0.546    -0.257     0.774     0.123     0.037 
COMPR_OPER_SIST_AGUA 
             Não    0.180     0         1           (reference)
   Não se aplica    0.606    -0.719     0.487     0.995     0.470 
             Sim    0.214    -0.286     0.751     0.130     0.027 
PLANTA_SAA_LOCAL 
      Dispensada    0.015     0         1           (reference)
             Não    0.006    -0.433     0.648       NaN       NaN 
   Não se aplica    0.591     0.747     2.111       NaN       NaN 
    Parcialmente    0.016    -0.679     0.507       NaN       NaN 
             Sim    0.372     0.232     1.261       NaN       NaN 
PECA_PB_ESCALA 
      Dispensada    0.015     0         1           (reference)
             Não    0.010    -0.990     0.372   444.246     0.998 
    Parcialmente    0.017     0.761     2.141   444.246     0.999 
             Sim    0.958     0.096     1.101   444.246     1.000 
DOC_CONSELHO 
      Dispensada    0.015     0         1           (reference)
             Não    0.018     0.411     1.509       NaN       NaN 
             Sim    0.968    -0.544     0.580       NaN       NaN 
ART_CAPTACAO 
      Dispensada    0.015     0         1           (reference)
             Não    0.007    -1.221     0.295       NaN       NaN 
   Não se Aplica    0.807     0.637     1.890       NaN       NaN 
             Sim    0.172     0.451     1.571       NaN       NaN 
ART_PB_PLAN_ORC 
      Dispensada    0.015     0         1           (reference)
             Não    0.018    -0.626     0.535   379.341     0.999 
    Parcialmente    0.047     0.217     1.243   379.341     1.000 
             Sim    0.921     0.276     1.317   379.341     0.999 
TITULARIDADE_TERRENO 
Certidão de Registro de Imóveis    0.127     0         1           (reference)
Declaração de posse de terreno (Portaria 154/09 Funasa)    0.669    -0.108     0.898     0.125     0.387 
Decreto de Desapropriação    0.059    -0.448     0.639     0.207     0.031 
      Dispensada    0.015     0.133     1.142       NaN       NaN 
Imissão de Posse    0.028    -1.596     0.203     0.401     0.000 
   Não se aplica    0.043    -0.151     0.860     0.237     0.523 
         Nenhuma    0.059    -0.403     0.668     0.257     0.117 
SUSTENT_DEVIDA 
      Dispensada    0.015     0         1           (reference)
             Não    0.048    -0.337     0.714   235.032     0.999 
             Sim    0.937     0.204     1.226   235.032     0.999 
PLAN_ORC_ADM_LOCAL 
      Dispensada    0.015     0         1           (reference)
             Não    0.033     0.121     1.129   325.233     1.000 
             Sim    0.953    -0.254     0.776   325.233     0.999 
LAUDO_HIDR_PERF 
      Dispensada    0.015     0         1           (reference)
             Não    0.008     0.564     1.757    85.436     0.995 
   Não se Aplica    0.816    -0.655     0.520    85.430     0.994 
             Sim    0.162    -0.042     0.959    85.433     1.000 
ACORDO_LEI_11445 
      Dispensada    0.015     0         1           (reference)
             Não    0.013     0.127     1.136       NaN       NaN 
             Sim    0.972    -0.260     0.771       NaN       NaN 
ETAPA_UTIL 
      Dispensada    0.015     0         1           (reference)
             Não    0.010     0.398     1.489       NaN       NaN 
             Sim    0.975    -0.531     0.588       NaN       NaN 
ANUN_CONCESS_AGUA_OPER 
      Dispensada    0.335     0         1           (reference)
             Não    0.021    -0.499     0.607       NaN       NaN 
   Não se aplica    0.114     0.145     1.156       NaN       NaN 
             Sim    0.529     0.228     1.256       NaN       NaN 
METAS 
      Dispensada    0.335     0         1           (reference)
             Não    0.053    -0.266     0.766    93.751     0.998 
             Sim    0.612     0.140     1.150    93.751     0.999 
REALIDADE_LOCAL 
      Dispensada    0.335     0         1           (reference)
             Não    0.006     0.422     1.525       NaN       NaN 
             Sim    0.658    -0.548     0.578       NaN       NaN 
OBRA_EM_EXECUCAO 
      Dispensada    0.335     0         1           (reference)
             Não    0.012    -0.479     0.620       NaN       NaN 
   Não se aplica    0.234     0.316     1.372       NaN       NaN 
             Sim    0.419     0.036     1.037       NaN       NaN 
TIPO 
    PAC 2 - 2011    0.405     0         1           (reference)
    PAC 2 - 2014    0.569    -1.094     0.335     0.139     0.000 
       SEMIÁRIDO    0.026     0.768     2.155     0.240     0.001 
SIT_OBRA_PAC 
         Análise    0.020     0         1           (reference)
        Aprovada    0.044    -0.259     0.772     0.323     0.421 
       Concluída    0.014     0.641     1.899     0.518     0.216 
        Execução    0.058     0.258     1.294     0.294     0.381 
   Não se aplica    0.865     0.407     1.502     0.443     0.359 
COMPR_TITULARIDADE 
      Dispensada    0.335     0         1           (reference)
             Não    0.071    -0.234     0.791       NaN       NaN 
   Não se aplica    0.070    -0.103     0.902       NaN       NaN 
             Sim    0.524     0.211     1.235       NaN       NaN 
LIC_AMB_EMPREEND 
      Dispensada    0.335     0         1           (reference)
Dispensado de licenciamento    0.149     0.284     1.328   156.350     0.999 
Empreendimento não licenciado    0.048    -0.406     0.667   156.350     0.998 
      LI emitida    0.143     0.257     1.293   156.350     0.999 
      LO emitida    0.027     0.256     1.292   156.350     0.999 
      LP emitida    0.005    -0.621     0.537   156.351     0.997 
Processo em análise no órgão ambiental    0.293     0.103     1.109   156.350     0.999 

Baseline parameters:
log(scale)                    5.001                 NaN       NaN 
log(shape)                    0.425               0.037     0.000 
Baseline life expectancy:  

Events                    555 
Total time at risk        443010 
Max. log. likelihood      -4064.2 
LR test statistic         356 
Degrees of freedom        62 
Overall p-value           0
Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(x$var)) : NaNs produzidos
```

I get negative values in main diagonal of the covariance matrix? Why does this happend, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I also had a problem in Python that resulted in a nonsensical, negative, covariate matrix. It turned out to be an overflow in the calculation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40095325/covariance-matrix-from-np-polyfit-has-negative-diagonal